# Error in String/character uppercase/lowercase conversion with loop

Tags: java, loops

I have been doing an assignment, and I'm stuck. If I enter the letters: `ahb`, it prints only the last letter `b` not the whole thing:

```
public void run() 
{
    String value;
    while (true) {
        try {
            value = (String) conB.remove();
            if(value != null) { {
                for(int i=0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                    if(Character.isDigit(value.charAt(i))) {
                        int x = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        bConWin.setData(" "+(x*2));
                    }
                    if(Character.isLowerCase(value.charAt(i))) {
                        char x = value.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
                        //changed.append(Character.toUpperCase(x));
                        bConWin.setData(" " +x);
                    }
                    if(Character.isUpperCase(value.charAt(i))) {
                        char x = value.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
                        bConWin.setData(" "+x);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you're printing anything.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: @Eran its a window, im not printing using system.out.print, im using a frame of type bConWin that i implemented.

Comment: @AhmadHeiba Does `bConWin.setData` append data to the window or overrides the current data with the new data?

Answer (score 0):

You are only ever assigning one character as bConWin's data. Here's a fix as well as some tidying:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String value = "HaaaOppSaN";
    if(value != null) {
        StringBuilder newValue = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            char x = value.charAt(i);

            if(Character.isLowerCase(x)) {
                x = Character.toUpperCase(x);
            } else {
                x = Character.toLowerCase(x);
            }

            newValue.append("" + x);
        }

        bConWin.setData(newValue.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer endless loop is not needed. The try without a catch block as well.

Take a look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String switched = switchCharacterCase("Hello World!");

    bConWin.setData(switched);

    System.out.println(switched);
}  

public static String switchCharacterCase(final String input) {
    StringBuilder switched = new StringBuilder();

    if(input != null) { // nothing to do here, return switched

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

            Character c = input.charAt(i);

            if(Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            } else {
                c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            }

            switched.append(c);
        }
    }

    return switched.toString();
}
```